# Plotting error "memory exhausted or requested size too large"

Tags: matlab, plot, octave

If I want to draw a `sin(x)` graph using octave, I would do

```
x = -6:0.1:6;
plot (x, sin(x));
```

and this works.

I wanted to draw a sigmoid function so I tried

```
x = -6:0.1:6;
plot (x, 1/(1+exp(-x)));
```

But this gives me

```
error: memory exhausted or requested size too large for range of Octave's index type -- trying to return to prompt
```

I tried with `x = -4:0.2:4;` and this time got

```
error: invalid conversion of NDArray to Matrix
error: evaluating argument list element number 2
```

What is the problem?

Comment: Try `plot (x, 1./(1+exp(-x)));`

Comment: Hmm. it works. What's the point? using real number 1(1.)? Oh, I see the element wise division now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in `1/(1+exp(-x))`. The error MATLAB throws is:

```
Error using  / 
Matrix dimensions must agree.
```

As per [Carandraug's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38977659/plotting-error-memory-exhausted-or-requested-size-too-large/38977918?noredirect=1#comment65313697_38977918) Octave fails with:

```
operator /: nonconformant arguments (op1 is 1x1, op2 is 1x121)
```

What you want is [elementwise division](http://mathworks.com/help/symbolic/rdivide.html) (note the dot):

```
x = -6:0.1:6;
plot (x, 1./(1+exp(-x)));
```

[image]

Comment: I see element wise dot operator is needed only when there can be confusion.  (like division, multiplication,..). Thanks.

Comment: @ChanKim `+`, `exp`, `sin` etc are already performed element wise (check their documentations). `/` and `*` however act as *matrix operators* generally, so you have to tell it explicitly to go element wise, i.e. put a dot before them.

Comment: Actually, Octave also fails on that operation with `operator /: nonconformant arguments (op1 is 1x1, op2 is 1x121)` and does not broadcast. The OP error probably comes from somewhere else and can't be reproduced with his code in Octave (I have tried on Octave 3.8, 4.0, and the unreleased 4.1).